How do I Program the MSP430FR2433 LaunchPad using the MSP-FET?
The below diagram shows the setup for the 2-wire JTAG (that is what I am trying to use).
I tried this, and it is not working.
What connections do I need to make between the MSP430 and the MSP-FET?
What do I need to do in Code Composer Studio to flash the device?
UPDATE: Got it working. The problem was the wrong end of the JTAG cable was plugged into the MSP-FET's black box, which reversed pin 1 and messed up the subsequent connections.


RGB Engineer - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + PDF title + its URL). (Doesn't apply here but if the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition.) TY

This has worked for me without fail for the past ~10 years.

(Drawing by me.)
The pin numbers listed on the chart near J901 correspond to the same numbers you have on your JTAG connector.
To flash the device, connect everything up(Computer to debugger, Debugger to your board), power up your board, and simply enter a Debug Session (the button with the "Beetle"/bug on it) and follow the prompts.
To flash the device outside of the debugger, TI provides a command-line tool you can use (useful for when your code is stable).
Sample Target Configuration (as requested):


What are your target configuration settings? I am using TI MSP430 USB1 right now, is that correct?

At what point is the process failing for you?  What do you see?  I have an HP desktop computer with notoriously finicky USB ports.  Even so, the TI MSP-FET has always been very reliable.  I show a connection to a MSP430F5529 above, but the same strategy works for the FR series as well.

My configuration looks the same as yours (I am using the MSP430FR2433 Launchpad), but I am getting a "Target not found" error.

Right after the "configuring debugger" prompt, I get the "error connecting to the target: unknown device"

Doesn't the launchpad have a USB header on it (a built in Debugger probe), where all you need to do is connect a USB cable to the PCB from your computer?    This USB connection also appears to power the board.  Do you wish to use the USB connection, or NOT use the Debug probe on the Launchpad board, and connect only the lines required for programming and debugging via SBW using an external programmer connect to your computer?

It does, but I am trying to get practice with the MSP-FET specifically.

If want to externally connect the SBW lines to an MSP-FET debugger, then you would need to remove the SBWTDIO and SBWTCK jumpers on the launchpad (all of them would be cooler, J101).  Then connect the SBW lines from the UC to the MSP-FET using your diagram above.  For simplicity (for now), do not connect a USB cable to the launchpad (but be sure to externally supply power to your board).  ...and to appease overlord Bill Gates, reboot your computer. ;~)  Try again.

Section 2.2.3 of slau739.pdf  "MSP430FR2433 LaunchPad™ Development Kit
(MSP‑EXP430FR2433)"

I tried that, but still no luck. The schematic says there is an on-board pull-up resistor - should I still put one of my own?

I'm looking at the launchpad schematic, and I do not see a pullup resistor for SBWTDIO.  Where do you see it?  Yes, you should add one, if it does not already exist.  Have you confirmed that power is being properly supplied to the target board from an external power supply?  ...and all jumpers on J101 are removed.

I believe it is tied to \R\S\T\ (S3). I checked with my oscilloscope, and SBWTDIO is being pulled up to 3.3V

Make sure the correct end of the JTAG cable is plugged in to the MSP-FET.
Try changing which side of the cable you are plugging in to the MSP-FET black box and use VCC_TOOL as a reference to tell if you have the correct pin orientation.
